# Get quarter number given two dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the next list with date quarters:

- 1 Jan-Mar
- 2 Apr-Jun
- 3 Jul-Sep
- 4 Oct-Dec

User can select any of them and this will be set as the first quarter. Next, he provides a year an month and I have to calculate the quarter number of the given date. As I don't mind the days, this are always set to 1. So, for example, if user selects the quarter 3, enter year 2017 and month 02 (2017-02-01), the result must be 3 because Jul-Sep become the number 1 and thus Jan-Mar the number 3.

So far, I can calculate the quarter number for static quarters:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse('2017-02-01');
int quarterNumber = ((date.Month - 1) / 3) + 1;
```

How can I modify this to get the correct quarter, no matter which is set as the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2017-02-01");
int quarterNumber = ((12+(date.Month - 1)-((x-1)*3)) %12 / 3) + 1;
```

where x is the selected quarter number from the list (1,2,3,4)

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed and works like a charm. Can you please provide me some short explanation on how this works or whats the pattern to solve this kind of math operations. I appreciate your help buddy!! Thank you

Comment: Sorry for late reply,

Comment: since your requirement is to make the selected quarter is the first  you should remove that amount of month from the date .

Comment: ((1-1)*3)) = 0 month removed for the first quarter

Comment: ((2-1)*3)) = 3 month removed for the 2nd quarter and so on.


adding 12+ to be sure that the amount of month after subtraction is always hold the amount of months you need , for example if the date is month 2 and a quarter is 3 (mean 6th month) the subtraction will make it 2-6 = -4, but with 12+ it will be 12+2-4 = 10, it is like calculating same quarter for the next year, then %12 to remove that second year effect